# iScroll not initializing until page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

I'm having a problem with iScroll not being initialized correctly in my jQuery mobile project. The iScroll plugin is only being used in one subpage, to allow horizontal scrolling on a big image (needed to make it work on Android, since their browser does not support it out of the box)...

The plugin works correctly if you access the URL directly, or if you refresh it manually. But when you access it via the menu, from another starting point, it won't work. I'm guessing this has something to do with the ajax loading in jQuery mobile, but setting data-ajax="false" to the link is not an option, since I need the whole thing to work well also as a home screen app in iOs (where links with data-ajax="false" opens in a new Safari window for some strange reason).

In the head tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
        refresh();
    }, 100);
}
window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
</script>
```

In the content section:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
    <img src="images/turkart.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I could force a refresh of the actual page after it's loaded, or is there any other way I force the iScroll to be initialized correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To answer you second question, i.e. is there another way: There is a very neat iScroll plugin for jQM at https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview that is very easy to implement and no need to worry about initialization problems